# How to adjust column Width in Laravel form-group

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

Here is simple contact form. Left side column display question that is "x1-question"
and Right side is text field that User type answer.

I would like to controll Left side width size by changing like ...type class="col-sm-5" or sm- 4. but I couldn't adjust what I want width size and it become big slip and view become really ugly.

Could you teach me right col-xx-x code in Laravel form-group please?

Currently when I type long texst question Left side(question part) this is really narrow.
i would like to it to more wide.

my Laravel Framework is 6.18.8

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">

         <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('x1') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
     <p>   {!! Form::label('x1', 'x1-question', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) !!} </p>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {!! Form::text('x1', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

            @if ($errors->has('x1'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('x1') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think its bootstrap 3

Comment: you can use total of 12 columns only, so if you are increase `col-sm-2` to `col-sm-4`, you need to decrease your sibling from `col-sm-10` to `col-sm-8`

Comment: Dear @Nisharg Shah Thank you for answering me. Sorry Is it bootstrap 3 ? Thank you. and Could you teach me where to add "col-sm-x" please ?

Comment: Dear @Nisharg Shah. Yes. please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a total of 12 columns only, so if you are increase `col-sm-2` to `col-sm-4`, you need to decrease your sibling from `col-sm-10` to `col-sm-8`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-12">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <p><label class="col-sm-4 control-label">x1-question</label></p>

                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="x1">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear @Nisharg Shah I know I have to use total of 12 columns. Could you write down for me the codes that how to add ? I tried to add col-sm-x but the whole desgine slip and looking bad.